# Differences between optical laser and amplifier

Tags: optics, laser, fiber-optics

I am preparing for an applied optoelectronics exam and I am having some trouble with telling the differences between optical fiber laser and optical amplifier. For now I only came up with following differences:

- No Bragg reflectors and optical resonators in amplifiers
- No signal conversion in optical amplifiers

I'm pretty sure there's more to it but I couldn't find anything that would answer this question fully.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between a fiber laser and a fiber amplifier is the cavity.

A laser (fiber laser or solid state laser) is an gain media, a pump and a cavity whereas a amplifier has no cavity. The cavity allow selecting the oscillating mode so there is no need to seed with a signal to generate a single frequency. Because it's initiated by noise. Whereas an amplifier need a signal seed.

You can make an analogy with Larcen effect. An audio amplifier acts just as its optical counterpart : it needs an input signal to amplify it. Now, if you get a microphone closer of the speaker plugged to the amplifier you form a loop and if unlucky you get that really annoying noise at a selected frequency.

For fiber laser, the cavity can be a ring cavity, a bragg cavity, or mirrors.

Answer (score 1):

An optical laser without a feedback mechanism is essentially an optical amplifier. The **feedback mechanism** can be made using 2 reflectors, mirrors, or gratings that creates an optical resonator cavity.

Another difference between optical amplifier and laser is that amplifier integrates **isolators** to avoid feedback, backreflection or lasing effects. The tunability of laser comes from bandwidth of its amplifier (active gain medium)

[image]

[image]